# jwt link param make the web page unfoundable

Tags: node.js, parameters, jwt

I am creating this post because I've a more than strange problem.

A brief background:
For an application that I am developing with nodejs, I have created a registration system where the user starts by entering their username and email address.
Then, the data is sent to the backend which sends everything in a token in order to send it to the user's mailbox (using nodemailer). The email contains a link with the token as a parameter.

Classic, so far, so good.

However, when I click on the link in order to be redirected to my site, the browser doesn't even bother to search. the page is inaccessible. I checked the validity of the token, the transmitted data, the link and the problem does not seem to come from there.

To conclude, I replaced the token in parameter by a character string typed at random and the browser finally redirected me to my site (a page where the token is checked) as expected at the start. I take it that the problem may be with the token.

I specify that this is not the first time that I code this kind of system, because it is the first time that I encounter this problem. How is it possible?
Any help would be welcome.

Here is a snippet of the code. I hope this will help you.

I create the token:

```
import { sign, verify, JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken';

// Fabrication de token pour inscrire l'utilisateur

export function createToken(name: string, email: string): string {
    const newToken = sign({
        name, email
    },
    process.env.SIGN_ADMIN as string, {
        expiresIn: '1h'
    })
    return newToken;
}

export function readTheToken(z: string): string | JwtPayload {
    const isToken = verify(z, process.env.SIGN_ADMIN as string,);
    try {
        if ( isToken === null) {
            throw new Error('token non valide');
            
        }
        return isToken;
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
}
```

I send the mail:

```
// a dev account is created to use smtp etheral server
async function createDevAccount() {

    try {
    let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

    if(!testAccount) {
        throw new Error('le compte n\'a pas été créé');
    }

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
          user: testAccount.user,
          pass: testAccount.pass,
        },
      });
      return transporter;
    } catch(err: any) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

// parameter link is : http://localhost:3000/redirect/token...

export async function sendingTo(link: string, email: string): Promise<boolean | undefined> {
    try {
        const transporter = await createDevAccount() as nodemailer.Transporter<SMTPTransport.SentMessageInfo>;

        let info = await transporter.sendMail({
            from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>',
            to: email,
            subject: "Confirmation pour inscripton",
            text: "Bienvenue sur Fantomize",
            html: mailForCreate(link),
          })
        
          console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

          console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

          return true;
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }
}
```

the resolver:

```
const devOrigin = 'http://localhost:3000';

export async function askCreateAdmin(_source: any, { name, email }: any): Promise<boolean | undefined> {
    try {
        const token = createToken(name, email);
        if(!token) {
            throw new Error('Le token n\'a pas été créé')
        }
        const rp = await sendingTo(`${ process.env.PROD_ORIGIN || devOrigin }/redirect/${token}`, email);
        if (rp != true) {
            throw new Error('Echec de l\'envoi');
        }
        return rp;
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code. It's quite impossible to answer your question without seeing your code.

Comment: sorry, I edited my post and added some code. All seem to work on this side so I wasn't sure which piece of code to post

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I placed the token in goal in my url without specifying the request variable. Therefore, the browser did not know if my token was a parameter or a file format (due to the token dots)

```
//before correction
const rp = await sendingTo(`${ process.env.PROD_ORIGIN || devOrigin }/redirect/${token}`, email);

// after correction
const rp = await sendingTo(`${ process.env.PROD_ORIGIN || devOrigin }/redirect?token=${token}`, email);
```